# AbsoluteToNanoseconds(), Uptime() deprecated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to replace some deprecated functions in Xcode with newer ones although I can't quite seem to figure out how to make it work properly:

```
AbsoluteTime startTime = UpTime();
float frameTime = UnsignedWideToUInt64(AbsoluteDeltaToNanoseconds(UpTime(),startTime))/1E9;
```

I get two warnings with this statement:

```
'UpTime' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.8
'AbsoluteDeltaToNanoseconds' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.8
```

I looked at various other threads here, and tried to use:

```
NSTimeInterval systemUptime = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime] / 1E9;
```

It didn't seem to return the same result though:

```
1: 0.011983 // deprecated function
2: 0.000431 // replacement function
1: 0.007218
2: 0.000431
1: 0.007084
2: 0.000431
```

I presume that there's something else I need to do to get the correct value for the new function?

Comment: Seem like there is already solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072575/7063478).

Comment: @nowaqq: I looked at that answer before (that's where I got the newer function), but I'm unsure how to translate it properly into my "frameTime" variable - thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4753909/7063478) you have getUptimeInMilliseconds implementation which replace AbsoluteToNanoseconds. You can do `uint64_t startTime = getUptimeInMilliseconds();` and then `float frameTime = ((uint64_t)getUptimeInMilliseconds() - startTime)/1E9;`.

Comment: @nowaqq: Unfortunately that did not work, as the result = `0.0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime]` returns the uptime in seconds, which is not a replacement for `UpTime()`. `mach_absolute_time()` should be a easy replacement for `UpTime()`.

As for `AbsoluteDeltaToNanoseconds()`, you can just write the code to calculate the absolute difference between the timestamps, and I believe `mach_absolute_time()` is already nanoseconds on macOS (but you should verify that). Then, as long as you properly cast values to (uint64_t) when doing the division, you should have the same precision in the float result.

Comment: Note that `mach_absolute_time()` is no longer nanoseconds on Apple Silicon (for people who find this years later, like me…).

Comment: Following from the previous comment by @Wevah: You should now be using clock_gettime_nsec_np(CLOCK_UPTIME_RAW) as Apple recommends it on the mach_absolute_time() page. That will give you uptime in ns consistently on Apple Silicon too.